# Css positioning

Tags: css, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” lang=”en” xml:lang=”en”>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table{

text-align:centre;
left:200px;
right:200px;
}
.karan
{
margin-top: 280px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="karan" href="#">asd</a>
<table>
<tr><th>haha</th><th>hoho</th></tr>
<tr><td>asdasd</td><td>asdasdasdas</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

I expect the result to be a link with a space of 280px on top of it, and a table with a space from about 200px from right side of the browser screen but the result is the same as it would be if there were no style tags, am i expecting something wrong.
What does left: right: property work for then?

Comment: For the anchor element, you need to set <code>display:block;</code> or <code>display:inline-block</code>, then only margin works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor tags are what's called inline elements, and as such you can't use margin-top on them. You can wrap the anchor tag in a div and apply the margin-top attribute to that.

As for the table, what you want are margins on either side of 200px, which you can't apply just using left and right.

The following code should work:

```
table {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-right:200px;
}

.karan {
    margin-top: 280px;
}


<div class="karan"><a href="#">asd</a></div>
<table>
    <tr><th>haha</th><th>hoho</th></tr>
    <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>asdasdasdas</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so if i want to place them at a particular place using left: right: etc. i have to put them necessarily in a division

Comment: @Karan no if you want to place them in a particular place you'd have to include a `position: absolute;` attribute along with left and right attributes. But top and bottom based attributes only apply to block level elements like divs and uls, not to inline elements like anchor tags and spans.

Comment: okay, so what is the problem with my table tag, it is not an inline element or is it?

Comment: @Karan this should help explain more about the anchor tags and the difference between inline and block display elements: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Comment: tables are block display elements. If you want to add margins on either side of your table you'd just use margin-right and margin-left. If you want to position your table in an exact location you'd use position: absolute, along with left and top attributes that define where to position the table relative to its containing element (in this case your body tag).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a postion value to the table, also your text-align value is mispelled:

```
table {
  text-align:center;
  left:200px;
  postion: absolute;
}
```

Additionally if you assign both right and left or top and bottom it serves to expand the box to those coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

`top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties are properties which are used for `element shifting`, meaning that they want to push element from the edge of the parent element. But they don't work for element which are `statically` positioned. `position: static;` is the default positioning set for any element, unless you specify otherwise. To enable element shifting, i.e. to be able to use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties, you should position your element `relatively`, `absolutely`, or `fixed`. Use this CSS:

```
.karan
{
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}

table
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 100px;
}
```